# Recursive formula in term of original value

Tags: calculus, analysis, recursive-algorithms

$$P_1=P_0G_{0,1}A_1\\
P_m=P_{m-1}G_{m-1,m}A_m+A_0\sum_{i=0}^{m-2}P_i G_{i,m}~~\text{for}~~m\geq 2$$

Is it possible to write $P_m$ in terms of only $P_0$, i.e., without other $P_j$ terms?

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary questions :

1) are the quantities involved scalars (and not matrices) ?

2) Are the $G_{i,j}$ and the $A_i$ known beforehand ?

If such is the case, I will try my best to cast your general question in a linear algebra setting.

Your 2nd equation(s) can be grouped into a matrix-vector form (may be I am re-discovering the original form of your issue...) :

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -G_{m,m-1}A_m&&\\&1&-G_{m-1,m-2}A_{m-1}&\\ &&\ddots \\ &&&\ddots \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}P_m\\P_{m-1}\\ \cdots \\ \cdots\end{pmatrix}=A_0 T \begin{pmatrix}P_m\\P_{m-1}\\ \cdots \\ \cdots\end{pmatrix}$$

where $T$ is a lower triangular matrix. Thus, by grouping everything in the LHS for example, you get an equation of the form $AP = 0$; the looked for vector $P$ belongs to the kernel of matrix $A$. The hope, then, is for an explicit knowledge of this kernel.

Comment: Yes, all are scalars and $G_{i,j}$ and $A_{i}$ are known and independent of $P_i$'s.

Comment: Yes you are right that I came up with this form as an intermediate step. But I really need to write the general term with only $P_0$.

Comment: My little experience in this type of calculation makes me pessismistic with regard to your objective. Why do you need such an "explicit" formula ?

Comment: Actually $A_i$s are my optimization parameters in which $P_0$ is the only input, e.g., it is the given water volume, and with the flow, depending on channel parameters $A_i, G_i$, $P_m$s are received volume at different stages. I feel comfortable with a simple linear equation (bit scared with matrix) for the max-min type optimization problem: $\max(\min(P_1,\cdots,P_M))$ So I have to decide $A_i$s in terms of $G_i$s and $P_0$.

Comment: I understand your point of view, for example to be able to work with an Excel spreadsheet without really programming, but sooner or later, like all people working in these kinds of models, you will find it very relieving to work with matrices.

Comment: Do you think that it is possible with this matrix form?

Comment: If it is possible through successive iterations (your way) it is possible through the matrix formulation ; matrix formulation is only a global way to describe things...

Comment: Is that $T$ a lower or upper triangular matrix? can you please specify if possible?